# Provisional headers are shown on stripe payment

Tags: php, google-chrome, stripe-payments

I have problem during stripe payment following are the detail issues:

```
Request URL:http://2017t.domain.com/base/apps/project/stripe.php
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Origin:http://2017t.domain.com
Referer:http://2017t.domain.com/base/apps/project/file.php?action=checkout
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
```

If i remove the stripe `ca-certificates.crt` file then it throw the `302 status`. if i keep that `ca-certificates.crt` file then Provisional headers are shown problem.

I have no `https://` url. The same code was working till yesterday, but not working today.